# How to return float value from parameter

Tags: c

I need to get float value from parameter

```
float aCoefficiants[50]=
{
-0.000890288188976378,
..
}
float bCoefficiants[50] =
{
 
89.1324281858268,
..
}

   float* cArray ;
   Get_Coefficient_From_Value(2211,(float*)&cArray);
   printf(">> out %f %f",cArray[0],cArray[1]);
```

And function:

```
void Get_Coefficient_From_Value(int32_t pulse, float * coefficient)
{
 
     coefficient[0] = aCoefficiants[0];
     coefficient[1] = bCoefficiants[0];
    printf(">> in %f %f\n",(coefficient[0]),(coefficient[1]));

}
```

in parameter that I expected: >> `in -0.000890 89.132431` But out values does not match with original >> `out-0.001010 99.323250`

How get float variables in parameter corrrectlu and solve this problem?

EDIT:

https://onlinegdb.com/Jy_ylNlVf

Comment: `float cArray[2]; Get_Coefficient_From_Value(2211, cArray);`

Comment: it doesnt work I get same out value again

Comment: Well then possibly something else is wrong. Please give a complete [mre].

Comment: I get this output >> out -0.001010 99.323250

Comment: Giving us output doesn't help considering we don't know the value of any of the variables. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I added simle version without arrays. I think its minimal now

Comment: @gogogo it's minimal, but not complete. We need a complete minimal program that we can compile and run.

Comment: If you made the right changes it should [work fine](https://ideone.com/1KktWH)

Comment: If you apply what is suggested in the first comment it works.

Comment: Like kaylum said: https://onlinegdb.com/MyOD2LEGoZ

Comment: I add original code in edited version link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float* cArray;
```

That is an uninitialised pointer and dereferencing it results in Undefined Behaviour. Change that to an actual array. The following complete program should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
 
void Get_Coefficient_From_Value(int32_t pulse, float * coefficient)
{
    coefficient[0] = -0.000890288188976378;
    coefficient[1] = 89.1324281858268;
    printf(">> in %f %f\n",(coefficient[0]),(coefficient[1]));
 
}
 
int main(void)
{
   float cArray[2];
   Get_Coefficient_From_Value(2211, cArray);
   printf(">> out %f %f",cArray[0],cArray[1]);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior:

```
float* cArray ;
Get_Coefficient_From_Value(2211,(float*)&cArray);
```

`cArray` is not pointing to anything valid. Further, you are casting the pointer to cArray to a float pointer and passing that in. (Technically, the pointer to an array is the array, but I digress).

Hence, when that function writes into cArray[0] and cArray[1], you are stomping on memory that doesn't belong to you.

Better:

```
float cArray[2] = {0};
Get_Coefficient_From_Value(2211,cArray);
```

When you invoke it that way, the cArray array will "degrade to a pointer" when passed in as a parameter. The two coEfficient assignments in that function will moving values into valid memory.